# how can we print the output of a code in gui , not in console?

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.6

i have a written piece of code of around 100 lines which is printing some output of around 20 lines. How can I print this output in GUI ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote this implementation for a project of mine, its in Python 2.7 but it should be easy to adapt it to Python 3.6

```
#!/usr/lib/python2.7/
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Tkinter import *
import ttk, collections

class GUI():    

    def __init__(self) :
        self.window = Tk()    

    def draw(self) :
        self.root = Frame(self.window,padx=15,pady=15,width=800,height=200)
        self.root.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.drawConsole()
        self.window.mainloop()

    def drawConsole(self) :
        self.consoleFrame = Frame(self.root, padx=15)
        self.consoleFrame.grid(column=0,row=4,sticky="EW",pady=10)
        self.logTest = Text(self.consoleFrame, height=15, state='disabled', wrap='word',background='black',foreground='yellow')
        self.logTest.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="EW")
        self.scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.consoleFrame, orient=VERTICAL,command=self.logTest.yview)
        self.scrollbar.grid(column=1,row=0,sticky=(N,S))
        self.logTest['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set        

    def writeToLog(self, msg):
        numlines = self.logTest.index('end - 1 line').split('.')[0]
        self.logTest['state'] = 'normal'
        if numlines==24:
            self.logTest.delete(1.0, 2.0)
        if self.logTest.index('end-1c')!='1.0':
            self.logTest.insert('end', '\n')
        self.logTest.insert('end', msg)
        self.logTest.see(END)
        self.logTest['state'] = 'disabled'

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    gui = GUI()
    gui.draw()
    gui.writeToLog("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a Python 3.x guy, but when it comes to tkinter, you can set labels with variables instead of using `print()`. So to get it on the GUI, you want to set labels with variables. This would look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
variable = StringVar()
variable.set(data_to_console) #You can use a variable with a string here or any string
label = Label(window, textvariable=variable)
label.grid(row=x, column=y)
```

So you take the strings that would be output into the console and use `.set()` to put it into a String Variable that tkinter can use. The Labels will allow for the data that would be printed to be in the GUI. Hope this helps!